# Can't get to property in razor foreach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm still fairly new to MVC and Razor and I'm hoping you can help me out with something. I am able to use the following code to just print the line (using @reply.GetProperty("PropertyName") but when I try to assign it to a variable (test) the code fails. Why is this and how can I get around it? I really need to be able to assign it and use it further in some other code.

```
    @foreach (var reply in CurrentPage.Children)
    {
        @reply.GetProperty("PropertyName")
        @{
            string test = reply.GetProperty("PropertyName");
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is ``GetProperty()``??

Comment: @ehsanSajjad It's a function in Umbraco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your View

```
@{
   string test = string.Empty;
 }

@foreach (var reply in CurrentPage.Children)
    {
        @reply.GetProperty("PropertyName")
        test = reply.GetProperty("PropertyName");

    }
```